# Поиск строки в файлах через cmd FIND

Tags: cmd, find

Можно ли в CMD Windows 10 искать строку в файлах и в файлах во вложенных папках через `find`?

Например, в .cpp файлах. Если да, то можно пример.

Comment: FOR выполнит перебор файлов. Чтобы лазить в подкаталоги, надо ему перенаправить вывод команды DIR. `FOR /F "ключи" %x IN ('dir /b /s x:\folder\*.cpp') DO (FIND ... | ...)`. Но искомая подстрока должна присутствовать строго в одной строке.

Comment: ¿Зачем на Windows10 использовать cmd, когда есть powershell?

Comment: В Powershell, например, так: Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Projects\\*.cpp' -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern 'Я ищу такую строку' -CaseSensitive